# Chaining instance methods in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, chaining, method-chaining

I would like create a class in python with method and sub-method.

Example what I want to do :

```
foo = Foo()
foo.playlist('my playlist').add('i_add_a_track_in_"my playlist".ogg')
foo.playlist('my playlist').delete('i_remove_this_track.ogg')
```

I have this code for now :

```
class Foo(object):
    def playlist(self, name):
        pass #my function...
    def add(self, track):
        pass #adding track
    def delete(self, track):
        pass #delete track
```

Please help me, I don't know how i can do it.

Thank you

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining

Comment: @MosesKoledoye I think we should choose another dupe that expresses the concept in your wikipedia link rather than shoehorning builtins.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Added

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, you want to chain method calls one after another? All you'd have to do is return `self` at the end of each function.

```
class Foo(object):
    ...   
    def playlist(self, name):
        ...
        return self

    ... # and so on
```

MVCE:

```
In [229]: class Foo:
     ...:     def __init__(self, data):
     ...:         self.data = data
     ...:
     ...:     def add(self, val):
     ...:         self.data += val
     ...:         return self
     ...:
     ...:     def sub(self, val):
     ...:         self.data -= val
     ...:         return self
     ...:     

In [231]: x = Foo(0)

In [232]: x = x.add(10).sub(5) # or just x.add(10).sub(5)

In [233]: x.data
Out[233]: 5
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, `foo.playlist('someplaylist').do_something()` should actually be a shortcut for

```
playlist = foo('someplaylist')
playlist.do_something()
```

where `playlist` is NOT a `foo` object (ie: `foo.do_something()` is not supposed to make any sense and should just raise an error) but an instance of a distinct class.

If that's indeed the case, you actually want two classes: `Foo` with method `playlist(...)` that returns a `Playlist` object, and `Playlist` with `add()` and `delete()` methods:

```
class Playlist(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def add(self, what):
        print("adding {} to playlist {}".format(what, self.name))

    def delete(self, what):
        print("deleting {} from playlist {}".format(what, self.name))


class Foo(object):
    def playlist(self, name):
        return Playlist(name)
```